# select_related multiple tables

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-select-related

i have 3 models:

```
class book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    publisher= models.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='publisher')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.publisher)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.publisher.id)
class reader(models.Model):
    publisher= models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
class publisher(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'm trying to get all the readers who reads specific book, i dont have connection between reader and book, 
only via publisher table, i tried to get this information with: Book.object.select_related(publisher__readers__id='x')
but I'm getting error.
It is possible to get information from multiple tables like my model?
thanks

Comment: If you want help tracking down an error, show the actual code and the error you're getting.  The answer below shows a clearly better way to set up your code, but I also see some other issues.  `Book.object` should raise an attribute error because it should be `Book.objects`.  Also: `select_related` does not actually fetch anything, it just sets the Queryset up to do a prefetch when you actually execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

I'm feeling your code a bit weird, if you follow the Django Good Practices, `related_name` parameters and some sense of what you want to do, it should be something like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='books')


class Reader(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='readers')


class Publisher(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

And then you have:

```
book = Book.objects.get(pk='<book_pk>')
readers = book.publisher.readers.all()
# or just
readers = Reader.objects.filter(publisher__books__pk='<book_pk>')
```

Your relation looks weird because you are creating a relation between between the `Reader` and the `Publisher`, instead of doing it with the `Book` itself. You should create a `ManyToMany` relation between `Reader` and `Book`, by doing that you have the scenario where: "A reader reads books, and more than one reader can read the same book.". Today you code means something like: "A read relates with a Publisher, which means that this Reader read all the Publisher Books", i don't see a lot of sense on it, sorry.